# matrix representation, relative to the standard basis, for bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Compute the matrix representation, relative to the standard basis, for the bilinear form $S: \mathbb{R}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by $S((x_{1}, y_{1}), (x_{2}, y_{2})) = x_{1}y_{2} - x_{2}y_{1}$

I assume that the standard basis is $ = \{(0,1),(1,0)\} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

I think that it is also valid to write write: $S(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix} x_{1}y_{2} - x_{2}y_{1}\end{bmatrix}$.

I know that any vector can be of the form $a(1,0) + b(0,1)$ but I do not know how to utilize all this 'info'.

I am unsure how to proceed further, all the other forum posts I have seen do not seem to answer this question, I apologize in advance if that is not the case. Any links or hints are appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Letting $e_{1} = (1,0)$ and $e_{2} = (0, 1)$, the matrix will have entries $S(e_{1}, e_{1})$, $S(e_{1}, e_{2})$, etc., but the details depend on your definitions and notational conventions. (And if it matters, your $S$ is real-valued, not vector-valued.) If that's not enough hint/suggestion, it would help to know how you define the matrix representation of a bilinear form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$M=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$

be the matrix representation of the bilinear form $S$. Then

$S((x_{1}, y_{1}), (x_{2}, y_{2})) = [x_1\quad y_1]\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

In order to determine the values of $a,b,c,d$, compute the RHS of the above equation and compare the result with $S((x_{1}, y_{1}), (x_{2}, y_{2})) =x_1y_2-x_2y_1$.